# wget not working in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, wget, osx-yosemite, os.system

I am using the os module to issue a wget request through python. It looks something like this:

```
os.system("wget 'http://superawesomeurl.com'")
```

If I issue the wget request straight from terminal, it works, but I have two problems:

1. When I build this in sublime, it give me the error: `sh: wget: command not found`
2. When I enter this into a python shell command line it sends the request but comes back bad: `400 bad request`

I noticed that other people don't use the quotes around the url, but in terminal this is the only way it works.
I am using python 2.7.8 and running Yosemite.

Comment: /usr/bin/wget works amazing.

Comment: `subprocess.check_call(['wget', 'some_url'])`, you don't need quotes in bash shell either

Answer (score 3):

Your code should work if wget is on your PYTHONPATH.

### But seriously, do not use wget in Python!

Better use a Python-native function like urlopen: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen
It's as simple as this:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
response = urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com").read()
```

Now `response` contains the whole contents of the html page. You can also use `readlines()` if you wanted to iterate over it line by line.
To save the html file to disk use:

```
download = open("index.html", "w")
download.write(response.read())
download.close()
```

Comment: I don't see how *this works for me* solves the problem

Comment: You're right, guys. I've just removed the "works for me" part and included an example of urlopen.

Comment: So I keep getting a bad request when I use urlopen. I'm not sure if this is because the link I'm using is for an API request with facebook, would that change anything?

Comment: urlopen does a simple HTTP GET request by default. For API requests you might need to send some data, which is usually rather done using HTTP POST (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen). Or you might need to authenticate first (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#examples - 4th example).

Comment: Now there is a python package called `wget`: https://pypi.org/project/wget/

Answer (score 0):

I would guess one of two problems:

1. wget is not in your path
2. wget is not installed (I'm not trying to insult you)

From a bash terminal type `which wget`.  That will tell you where `wget` is installed on your system.

```
[sri@localhost ~]$ which wget
/usr/bin/wget
[sri@localhost ~]$
```

If `which` didn't locate `wget` then use `find`:

```
sudo find / -name wget
```

Once you know the path to wget, try adding the complete path to `wget` in your call to `os.system`:

```
[sri@localhost ~]$ which wget
/usr/bin/wget
[sri@localhost ~]$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Feb 19 2014, 13:47:40) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.system('/usr/bin/wget "www.asciitable.com"')
--2014-11-11 09:29:52--  http://www.asciitable.com/
Resolving www.asciitable.com (www.asciitable.com)... 192.185.246.35
Connecting to www.asciitable.com (www.asciitable.com)|192.185.246.35|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.1’

    [ <=>                                                                ] 6,853       --.-K/s   in 0.006s  

2014-11-11 09:29:53 (1.06 MB/s) - ‘index.html.1’ saved [6853]

0
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure wget is on your PYTHONPATH

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
wget = Popen(["wget", "http://superawesomeurl.com"],stdout=PIPE).read()
print wget
```